# How to remove Office-Js addin

Tags: office-js

I try to create new Office-JS addin and now need to make changes )

How to remove old development? 
How to reinstall it?

Answer (score 2):

You only need to reinstall if you have made changes to the add-in manifest file. All other changes are in files that are hosted with the web application of the add-in, so they are automatically picked up by the add-in when you deploy the changed files.

If you make a change in the add-in manifest, you simply go to the catalog where the manifest file is deployed and copy your new version over the old one. Exit from the Office application and relaunch it.